# How to implement Object Databases in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, nosql

I started my project in Asp.net MVC(c#) & SQL Server 2005.I want to implement Object Databases in my project.
While searched in google i found "[MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home)" & [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/about/productinformation/)

I didn't have enough knowledge in Object Databases & which one best suited for SQL Server 2005.

Please suggest a good example/reference regarding Object Databases implementation in Asp.net MVC application

Comment: This might be better as a question and not a wiki.

Comment: I am sorry,now i will correct it

Comment: @amexn, could you please explain why you (need) mongodb rather than something a little more widely used such as linq2sql?  if all you want is objects representing your model then...

Comment: I read an article regarding Object Databases.so i need to try in my project http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2010/03/15/first-toe-in-the-water-with-object-databases-db4o.aspx

Comment: Both MongoDB and db4o are independent databases - they replace, not work with, SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Why dont you revise your question to make it more clear? As other responded, MongoDB and DB40 are independent, they have nothing to do with SQL Server. Either you are going to use those two for your datastore or your question is wrong and you are talking about ORM Mappers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a good introduction to MongoDB with C#, you might look at this series:

- http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/1057
- http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/1107
- http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/1145
- http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/1165

As for using it from ASP.net MVC, I don't know of any reference-implementation yet.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to get started in MongoDb with asp.net MVC. In that case get the latest community supported drivers for Mongodb from http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp and follow this step by step blog post http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/13/experimenting-with-mongodb-from-c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Rob Conery's blog at http://www.wekeroad.com. He's been doing a lot of work lately with MongoDB. His main project which provides an object persistence interface, although it is still very much a work in progress, can be found on [github as NoRM](http://github.com/atheken/NoRM).

Answer (score -2):

What exactly do you want to implement? What do you mean saying "Object Databases"? Most likely you just need an ORM (Object-Relational Mapper) tool to work with RDBMS in object-oriented way. You can find list of ORMs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software).

Comment: Linq To Sql comes to mind as it's really easy and requires no code at all.  then maybe implement a repository pattern.  I removed my answer saying as much but then thought @amexn was thinking more in terms of MongoDB.

Comment: I need db4o/MongoDb Object Database

Comment: he refers to object database as a system that directly store/retrieve application objects (usually through binary serialization) as opposed to relational ones that store tables, rows etc.